# Website jumps to middle content on load. One page design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fotorama, jquery-scrollify

I have one page design with 3 sections.

```
<section>
<div class="page1">
content
</div>
</section>

<section>
<div class="page2">
content
</div>
</section>

<section>
<div class="page3">
content
</div>
</section>
```

I use scrollify.js to scroll to next section on mousewheel. In my first section I have fotorama loaded. When I reload the page, the page shows the second section for a second before it jumps to first section when fotorama is loaded.
I know that I can use Javascript delay function to delay the second and third section. But will this be the right thing to do? Or is there a way to use a function that can wait for the first section to load until the second and third section is loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I managed to fix this problem by setting a min-height to page1.

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

Comment: You should edit your question and add the answer in it, instead of replying to your own question.